# Get Xpath string of an element that I got by ID or name etc.. Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have this element and I want to access its Xpath by code, ***not find element by Xpath like find_element(By.XPATH,'myXpath')*** and not get xpath it manually on the browser

```
today = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'today')
day = today.get_attribute("data-day")
xpathString = today.get_xpath() # <--- this function doesn't exist
```

we can get the attribute of an element by ***get_attribute()*** function, but I couldn't find the function that returns the Xpath of the element.

please is it possible?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This return the full xpath of the element `el` whose class name is `today`, i.e. `/html/.../el`

```
xpathString = driver.execute_script("""
var el = arguments[0];
aPath ="";
while (el.tagName!='HTML'){
    parentEle=el.parentNode;
    if(parentEle.querySelectorAll(el.tagName).length>1){
        childIndex = 0;
        parentEle.querySelectorAll(el.tagName).forEach(function(cEle){
           childIndex= childIndex+1;
           if(cEle === el){
             aPath = el.tagName + "[" + childIndex + "]" + "/" +aPath;
           }
        })

    }else{
         aPath = el.tagName + "/" +aPath;
    }
    el=el.parentNode;
}
return "/html/"+aPath.substring(0,aPath.length-1).toLowerCase();
""", today)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, my objective is to get the Xpath string of an element that I already found by class_name not get the element by Xpath.
Like : "xpathString = today.get_xpath()" but this function does not exist

Comment: @YassineBagdad For example the full xpath of the answer (`#answer-72273462`) which can be found in the inspector tool is `/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]`. Do you mean this?

Comment: yes exactly, I want to get like this of an element that we already have found, thanks.

Comment: thank you so much !! you're amazing !! is there a way to generate the short form of XPath like : "//*[@id="datePickerDesk"]/div/ul/li[1]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]" ? but thank you so much, this is so helpful already !!